# sqlite3 unique on multiple criteria

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to create a table in sqlite3 that will store user field selections and make each combination of user_id, table, and name_id unique. However running the following gets me "ERROR: near "table": syntax error"

```sql
CREATE TABLE preftest (
'id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
'user_id' INTEGER NOT NULL, 
'table' TEXT NOT NULL, 
'name_id' INTEGER NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT userpref UNIQUE(user_id, table, name_id))
```

Is there some issue with combining text and integer columns in a unique constraint?

Answer (score 2):

`table` is a [SQLite keyword](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

You need to use `'table'` instead of `table` in the constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE preftest (
'id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
'user_id' INTEGER NOT NULL, 
'table' TEXT NOT NULL, 
'name_id' INTEGER NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT userpref UNIQUE(user_id, 'table', name_id))
```

Comment: Properly, it would be `"table"` and not `'table'`, since you're quoting a name and not a literal. [SQLite also supports](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) `[table]` and `\`table\`` though these are not standard SQL.